# how to SQL order by with this query

Tags: sql

i'm trying to order data with sql query, but after few days trying everything i don't have ideas how to do that, so, I made this query

```
SELECT bm, SUM(CASE WHEN glasao = 'da' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN glasao = 'ne' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Ukupno u Bazi], SUM(CASE WHEN glasao = 'da' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                         AS Glasali, SUM(CASE WHEN glasao = 'ne' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Nisu Glasali]
FROM            dbo.siguranglas
WHERE bm IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36') GROUP BY bm ORDER BY bm DESC
```

And i got this output:

```
9   1   0   1
8   9   0   9
4   1   0   1
29  3   2   1
28  1   0   1
26  3   2   1
17  1   1   0
13  2   1   1
```

The question is, how to order first columnt to go like this:

```
4   1   0   1
8   9   0   9
9   1   0   1
13  2   1   1
17  1   1   0
26  3   2   1
28  1   0   1
29  3   2   1
```

And if i can...one more question, can someone help me for one more thing, i want for all this to have one more column with 
(Column3 * (column3 + column4)) * 100 AS Percent

i tried many things and read many posts but no luck :P Maybe thi is not possible?

Comment: BTW sry for my bad english :P

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Try sql ascending not Desc

Comment: oh, i tried that many times... no luck!

Comment: @Alex K. man you are my man! i didn't even thing about strings and integers :(

Answer (score 0):

They are stored as textual values so are sorted as such; for numeric sorting they need to be numeric:

```
 order by cast(bm as int) asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the **BM** column before **Order by**

Try this

```
        SELECT bm, SUM(CASE WHEN glasao = 'da' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN glasao = 'ne' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Ukupno u Bazi], SUM(CASE WHEN glasao = 'da' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
               AS Glasali, SUM(CASE WHEN glasao = 'ne' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Nisu Glasali]
        FROM  dbo.siguranglas
        WHERE bm IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17'        
                     '18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32',
                     '33','34','35','36')
        GROUP BY bm 
        ORDER BY cast(bm as int)DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

From the detail given, I dont think the column bm used in Group by and order by is a integer column. First, convert that into a integer column.

```
select *, (Glasali * (Glasali + Nisu Glasali)) * 100 as percent
from
(
SELECT bm, SUM(CASE WHEN glasao = 'da' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN glasao = 'ne' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Ukupno u Bazi], SUM(CASE WHEN glasao = 'da' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                         AS Glasali, SUM(CASE WHEN glasao = 'ne' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Nisu Glasali]
FROM            dbo.siguranglas
WHERE bm IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36') GROUP BY bm ORDER BY bm DESC
) a 
order by cast(bm as integer)
```

BTW, I dont think your calculation will be a right way to calculate percent. CAST is an oracle function

Comment: Cast exists in say SQL server too, no?

Answer (score 0):

The current result, "bm" column appears to be a string, right?

If so, you need to perform a cast on the field...

Answer (score 0):

I think this is SQL server. Your question is not very clear but I guess you meant this:

```
WITH  preSum ( bm, Glasali, [Nisu Glasali] )
        AS (
             SELECT bm, SUM(CASE WHEN glasao = 'da' THEN 1
                                 ELSE 0
                            END),
                    SUM(CASE WHEN glasao = 'ne' THEN 1
                             ELSE 0
                        END)
             FROM   dbo.siguranglas
             WHERE  bm IN ( '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10',
                            '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18',
                            '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26',
                            '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34',
                            '35', '36' )
             GROUP BY bm
           )
  SELECT  bm, Glasali + [Nisu Glasali] AS [Ukupno u Bazi], Glasali,
          [Nisu Glasali],
          Glasali / ( Glasali + [Nisu Glasali] ) * 100 AS [percent]
  FROM    preSum
  ORDER BY cast(bm as int) DESC;
```

Comment: Yes it's SQL server, whent i load sql qurry and pass into integers in vb.net, i calculate percent, yoour code is wrong :P it gives me wrong percents :(

Comment: it should back something like 
`4 1 0 1 0`

`8 9 0 9 0`

`9 1 0 1 0`

`13 2 1 1 50`
`17 1 1 0 100`
`26 3 2 1 67`
`28 1 0 1 0`
`29 3 2 1 67`

Comment: it should back something like <br/>
`4 1 0 1 0`
<br/>
`8 9 0 9 0`
<br/>
`9 1 0 1 0`
<br/>
`13 2 1 1 50`<br/>
`17 1 1 0 100`<br/>
`26 3 2 1 67`<br/>
`28 1 0 1 0`<br/>
`29 3 2 1 67`<br/>

Comment: Wish I could understand what you mean.

Comment: I will make pictures :P just a sec

Comment: Probably when you are saying [percent] you really meant a percent but you used a wrong formula? * instead of / ? Glasali / (Glasali + [Nisu ...]) * 100

Comment: Ok, i made it in excel...
[link](http://i66.tinypic.com/2zgww0w.png)

formula in excel is: (Glasali / (Glasali+Nisu glasali))*100

Comment: You don't need excel, you only need correct formula.

Comment: I mean, if that is the correct formula in excel do the same in the above query. Replace first * with /. Editing for you.

Comment: It doesn't work, i tried to change * -> / , something bad is happening :/